# How to iterate through XML in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML document in a text file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
    <Property Name="DisplayName" Type="System.String">SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Property>
    <Property Name="ServiceState" Type="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServiceState">Running</Property>
  </Object>
  <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
    <Property Name="DisplayName" Type="System.String">SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)</Property>
    <Property Name="ServiceState" Type="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServiceState">Stopped</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

I want to iterate through each object and find the `DisplayName` and `ServiceState`. How would I do that? I've tried all kinds of combinations and am struggling to work it out.

I'm doing this to get the XML into a variable:

`[xml]$priorServiceStates = Get-Content $serviceStatePath;`

where `$serviceStatePath` is the xml file name shown above. I then thought I could do something like:

```
foreach ($obj in $priorServiceStates.Objects.Object)
{
    if($obj.ServiceState -eq "Running")
    {
        $obj.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

And in this example I would want a string outputted with `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`

Comment: Your XML appears to be serialized directly from in memory objects. Is there a reason you wouldn't just deserialize them back into memory?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

PowerShell has built-in XML and XPath functions.
You can use the Select-Xml cmdlet with an XPath query to select nodes from XML object and then
.Node.'#text' to access node value.

```sh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $serviceStatePath
$nodes = Select-Xml "//Object[Property/@Name='ServiceState' and Property='Running']/Property[@Name='DisplayName']" $xml
$nodes | ForEach-Object {$_.Node.'#text'}
```

Or shorter

```sh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $serviceStatePath
Select-Xml "//Object[Property/@Name='ServiceState' and Property='Running']/Property[@Name='DisplayName']" $xml |
  % {$_.Node.'#text'}
```

Comment: I've added some explanation.

Comment: You can also navigate the document using the familiar property syntax: `($xml.Objects.Object | ? { $_.ServiceState -eq "Running" }).DisplayName`

Comment: The explicit conversion to [xml] did it for me.  Without the conversion, it returns the xml (as string) and the parsing does not work.  No error - of course.

Comment: What version of Powershell was this introduced in?

Comment: `Get-Content` is the wrong way to load XML, because it doesn't respect the `encoding` attribute of the XML header. Most of the time we get lucky, only because many XML documents are UTF-8 encoded, which happens to be the default encoding used by `Get-Content` nowadays. Still it's wrong, for more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264118/7571258

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without the [xml] cast.  (Although xpath is a world unto itself.  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp)

```
$xml = (select-xml -xpath / -path stack.xml).node
$xml.objects.object.property
```

Or just this, xpath is case sensitive.  Both have the same output:

```
$xml = (select-xml -xpath /Objects/Object/Property -path stack.xml).node
$xml


Name         Type                                                #text
----         ----                                                -----
DisplayName  System.String                                       SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
ServiceState Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServiceState Running
DisplayName  System.String                                       SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)
ServiceState Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServiceState Stopped
```