# Loop through XML files powershell

Tags: xml, loops, powershell

I am trying to extract some content from XML files. I have what I need working for one file but I need to do it for all files in a directory. So far what I have is:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\rasuser\Desktop\import *.xml -recurse

foreach ($file in $files){

$MyXml = [xml](Get-Content $file)

#$path = $file.ExportedContentItem.path
#$name = $file.ExportedContentItem.name
#$GUID = $file.ExportedContentItem.ID

#$path + "/" + $name + " > "+$GUID

}
```

I'm not really understanding how to import read in the content to an XML format. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read XML in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509358/how-to-read-xml-in-powershell)

Comment: You say your code works for one file, but you didn't say in which way it stops working when you apply it to several files in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I was navigating the XML correctly when using it on a single file using Get-Content rather than Get-ChildItem. When I try to loop the above code I'm unable read the XML content into $myXml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your XML looks like this `<doc><foo name='fooname'><bar>bar content</bar></foo></doc>` you access the content like so:

```
$MyXml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFile)
$MyXml.doc.foo.name
$MyXml.doc.foo.bar
```

Comment: Also you might want to explicitly declare "$MyXml" as an XML like:
[xml]$MyXml = Get-Content $xmlFile

Comment: Yeah, that would help.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
function list-xml-files() {
    get-childitem -recurse -force | ? { -not $_.psisdirectory } | ? { $_.name.endswith('.xml') } 
}

function list-data([xml]$xml) {
    $path = $xml.ExportedContentItem.path
    $name = $xml.ExportedContentItem.name
    $ID = $xml.ExportedContentItem.ID
    [string]::Format("{0}/{1} > {2}", $path, $name, $ID)
}

list-xml-files | % { [xml](get-content $_) } | ? { $_.ExportedContentItem } | % { list-data $_ }
```

This code follows a more functional style of programming. '%' is a `map`, '?' is a `filter`.

It showcases several nice features of PowerShell. You might want to [install PowerShell 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34595) (you need .NET 4.0 as well) and you will be able to explore the various PowerShell features via IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error when trying to read the individual xml files path. I solved it by using  $_.fullname:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\rasuser\Desktop\import *.xml -recurse | 
% { 
    $file = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)

    $path = $file.ExportedContentItem.path
    $name = $file.ExportedContentItem.name
    $GUID = $file.ExportedContentItem.ID

    $out = $path + "/" + $name + "`t" + $GUID

    $out
}
```