# How to extract users from the line

Tags: string, powershell, parsing

I need to extract usernames from lines similar to this one. The usernames are variable, so I imagine this has to be attacked with regex. (I am clueless about how to pull this off).

```
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">USER1</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="1">USER2</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="2">USER3</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="3">USER4</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="4">USER 5</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
```

Comment: if you add `<RowGroups>` above the 1st line you will have valid XML. if you load that & coerce it to XML , you can use `$XML_Stuff.RowGroups.RowGroup.RowGroup.RowTotal.'#text'` to get all the user names in an array that can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

See answers for PowerShell and XML like [How to iterate through XML in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509358/how-to-iterate-through-xml-in-powershell)

And also look into things like the below code

```
$data = @'
<RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">USER1</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="1">USER2</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="2">USER3</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="3">USER4</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="4">USER 5</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
'@


$xml = [xml]$data

foreach ($row in $xml.RowGroups.RowGroup.RowGroup.RowTotal)
{
    $row.'#text'
}
```

Comment: What's up with the trailing @?

Comment: @ncfx1099 - that is the closing `'@` of a here-string. [*grin*] take a look at `Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules` for some details.