# How to parse XML in Powershell with Select-Xml and Xpath?

Tags: linux, xml, powershell, .net-core, parsexml

obvious output for this example would be the date and time.

---

In the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18509358/4531180) of iterating over an `xml` document, how is this document correctly cast or [converted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65233934/4531180) to `xml` in `Powershell` dotnet core on `Linux`?

```
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> 
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> Select-Xml -Xml (Get-Date | ConvertTo-Xml) -XPath "/Objects/Object"

Node   Path        Pattern
----   ----        -------
Object InputStream /Objects/Object

PS /home/nicholas/flwor> 
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> (Get-Date | ConvertTo-Xml).OuterXml                                
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Objects><Object Type="System.DateTime">12/10/2020 5:12:45 AM</Object></Objects>
PS /home/nicholas/flwor>
```

*updated with the simplest possible example.*

So, this example is `xml` but:  how is it parsed or queried with xpath?

alternate solution given in IRC:

```
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> 
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> $date.SelectSingleNode('/Objects/Object').'#text'
12/10/2020 5:07:04 AM
PS /home/nicholas/flwor>
```

no doubt that's doable with `Select-Xml` and `Xpath`.

Comment: Use quotes: `$serviceStatePath = './serviceState.xml'` or use a named (-Path) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

if awkward, this works:

```
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> 
PS /home/nicholas/flwor> Select-Xml -Xml (Get-Date | ConvertTo-Xml) -XPath "/Objects/Object" |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node

Type            #text
----            -----
System.DateTime 12/10/2020 5:23:39 AM

PS /home/nicholas/flwor>
```

the help files had a similar example.

Comment: Returns date value directly: `(Get-Date | ConvertTo-Xml | Select-Xml "/Objects/Object").Node.InnerText`