# How to print a list of xml elements and their properties in the Powershell REPL console?

Tags: linux, xml, powershell, xpath, read-eval-print-loop

Referencing:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/

and:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264118/4531180

how is a list of  elements and their properties printed?

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $file = resolve-path('./bookstore.xml') 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $doc.load($file)                                           
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $doc.bookstore.book[1].author.first-name
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  $doc.bookstore.book[1].author.first-name
     |                                     ~~~~~
     | Unexpected token '-name' in expression or statement.

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $doc.bookstore.book[1].author           

first-name last-name
---------- ---------
Margaret   Atwood

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $doc.bookstore

bk          book
--          ----
urn:samples {book, book, book, book}

PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

Comment: Be careful with your quoting, I would advise you steer well clear of smart, _(curly)_, quotes, `“./bookstore.xml”`, and use dumb, _(straight)_, quotes instead, `"/bookstore/book[2]"`.

Comment: Ohhhh, that's a copy paste from another website.  I didn't see, thanks.  but, not the problem as the file loads fine.

Comment: I'd wager that the forum software has not changed only one pair of straight quotes, and left all of the others untouched. If you really did copy/paste them, then you've used them, _(the only other alternative is that you edited the pasted information later, and in doing so have introduced them yourself)_. I see you've now edited your comment above! as well as changing your code and output completely too!

Comment: it was in fact a copy paste from that website, and I was just omitting to specify "book" in the dot operator. but thanks for checking it out.  I understand your point.

Comment: @Compo: While avoiding non-ASCII quote characters is generally advisable, note that PowerShell happily accepts so-called typographic quote characters as well - the only caveat is that your source-code file must be properly encoded (which in Windows PowerShell means a Unicode encoding _with BOM_) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375).

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Comment: In other words: `resolve-path('./bookstore.xml')` -> `resolve-path './bookstore.xml'` or even `resolve-path ./bookstore.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To address the *for-display formatting* problem:**

If you look closely at the sample output [from your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265246/45375), you'll see that even though the display is *mostly* helpful, the value of the `author` property is `author` instead of showing the (presumed) `first-name` and `last-name` child-element values.

The problem is that **PowerShell's default output formatting represents child elements that have**:

- **at least one *attribute***
- **and/or at least one child element *themselves***

**by the element's *name* only.**

Especially **with deeply nested elements this results in *unhelpful output*.**

**Workarounds**, possibly in combination:

- **Access the [`.OuterXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.OuterXml) or `.InnerXml` property** of such elements, which contains the full XML *text* of the element with / without the element's tags themselves.

  - This will likely only be helpful with perhaps at most another level of nesting will be visually helpful, given that the XML text is a *single-line* representation that is *not* pretty-printed.
  - You can **pipe `.OuterXml` / `InnerXml` values to a *pretty-printing* function**, which **requires some extra work**, however, because no such functionality is directly exposed by PowerShell.
- Use **[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)** (or, for display purposes only, a `Format-*` cmdlet such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)) with **[calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375)**.

  - While this allows you full control over what is displayed, it is more work.

See the examples below.

---

```sh
# Sample XML document
$xmlDoc = [xml] @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>
        <first-name>Matthew</first-name>
        <last-name>Gambardella</last-name>
      </author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>
        <first-name>Kim</first-name>
        <last-name>Rall</last-name>
      </author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
   </book>
</bookstore>
"@
```

---

To get a helpful representation of all `<book>` elements *including the `<author>` child elements' `<first-name>` and `<last-name`> child elements* **via `Select-Object` and a calculated property**:

```sh
$xmldoc.bookstore.book | Select-Object id, 
   @{ n='author'; e={ $_.author.'first-name' + ' ' + $_.author.'last-name'} }, 
   title, genre, price, publish_date, description
```

This yields (note how the `author` property now lists first and last name):

```
id           : bk101
author       : Matthew Gambardella
title        : XML Developer's Guide
genre        : Computer
price        : 44.95
publish_date : 2000-10-01
description  : An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.

id           : bk102
author       : Kim Rall
title        : Midnight Rain
genre        : Fantasy
price        : 5.95
publish_date : 2000-12-16
description  : A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.
```

---

To get a helpful representation of all `<book>` elements via **pretty-printed XML**, via an auxiliary [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument) instance:

```sh
# Load the assembly that contains XDocument.
# Note: Required in Windows PowerShell only, and only once per session.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

$xmldoc.bookstore.book | ForEach-Object {
  ([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $_.OuterXml).ToString()
}
```

This yields (a pretty-printed XML representation):

```xml
<book id="bk101">
  <author>
    <first-name>Matthew</first-name>
    <last-name>Gambardella</last-name>
  </author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk102">
  <author>
    <first-name>Kim</first-name>
    <last-name>Rall</last-name>
  </author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
</book>
```

Note that you could wrap the formatting code in a simple (filter) function named `Format-Xml` that you could put in your `$PROFILE` file (in *Windows PowerShell*, also place the `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq` there, above it):

```
filter Format-Xml { ([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $_.OuterXml).ToString() }
```

Now the formatting is as simple as:

```
$xmldoc.bookstore.book | Format-Xml
```

Answer (score 1):

**To address the *syntax error* shown in your question**:

```bash
# BROKEN: `first-name` cannot be used without quoting
$doc.bookstore.book[1].author.first-name

# OK:
$doc.bookstore.book[1].author.'first-name'
```

Element name `first-name`, surfaced in PowerShell as a *property name*, cannot be used *without quotes*, because the `-` is then interpreted as the *subtraction operator*, resulting in the error that you saw.

In short:

- Only letters, digits, and `_` (underscores) can be used in unquoted *property names*; ditto for unquoted *variable names*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- When in doubt, *quote*.

---

**[1] Exact rules for identifier names in PowerShell**:

More accurately, **PowerShell permits an identifier to be unquoted if it is composed *solely* of characters from one of the following Unicode categories** (defined in .NET as enumeration [`System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory); the [two-letter shorthands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) listed in parentheses can be used with `\p{<shortCategoryName>}` in regular expressions):

- [`UppercaseLetter`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu) (`Lu`)
- [`LowercaseLetter`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll) (`Ll`)
- [`TitlecaseLetter`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt) (`Lt`)
- [`ModifierLetter`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm) (`Lm`)
- [`OtherLetter`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo) (`Lo`)
- [`DecimalDigitNumber`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd) (`Nd`) - except as the *first* character (variable names don't have this restriction)
- [`_`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5f) ("low bar", more typically: "underscore", the only allowed *symbol*)

Types of *identifiers*:

- **property names** (`.foo`)
- **keys in hashtable literals** (`@{ foo = ... }`)
- **variable names** (`$foo`)

---

**Identifiers *do* support additional characters, but then require *additional syntax***:

Identifiers that do not adhere to the above rules must be:

- *property names* and *hashtable keys*: quoted (`'last-name'` or `"last-name"`)
- *variable names*: enclosed in `{...}` (`${last-name}`)

---

Note that **extended rules apply to *command names*** (names of functions, cmdlets, script or executable files as well as aliases thereof) **and *module names***:

- In addition to the above, the following are allowed *without quoting*:

  - [`-`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d) ("hyphen", "minus", loosely: "dash")
  - [`.`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e) ("period", "full stop")
  - In file *paths* also: [`\`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5c)) and [`/`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2f))

Among command names, with the exception of function and cmdlet names (which you cannot even *define* with other characters), you can get away with using additional characters in names, as long as you *quote* the command name on invocation.

However, doing so is ill-advised, as users will generally expect commands not to require such quoting; to use a contrived example: `Set-Alias 'a&b' Get-Date; & 'a&b'` technically works, but the awkwardness of the invocation (quoting, which then requires `&`) makes this a poor choice.

Answer (score 0):

just wasn't using `books`:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $doc.bookstore.book

genre           : novel
publicationdate : 1997
ISBN            : 1-861001-57-8
title           : Pride And Prejudice
author          : author
price           : 24.95

genre           : novel
publicationdate : 1992
ISBN            : 1-861002-30-1
title           : The Handmaid's Tale
author          : author
price           : 29.95

genre           : novel
publicationdate : 1991
ISBN            : 1-861001-57-6
title           : Emma
author          : author
price           : 19.95

genre           : novel
publicationdate : 1982
ISBN            : 1-861001-45-3
title           : Sense and Sensibility
author          : author
price           : 19.95


PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

whoops.