# PowerShell: Referencing a property with spaces

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that will check a registry key/value. If the value is a certain version, write an output. If the value is not that version, then create a new value. The problem I am coming across is the property is split into two words.

The key is hklm:software\dg

The value name is "Agent version"

The value data is 7.8.5.005

I have tried the script below but I'm just not familiar with how to properly check the version of the value "Agent version" since it is split into two words. The script always creates the new test value. I have tried double quotes, single quotes, curly brackets around agent version. Nothing seems to work. If there is an easier way to do this, I am all ears. Thanks in advance!

```
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path hklm:software\dg

if($val.'agent version' -eq 7.8.5.005) {
Write-Host Agent is current -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
New-ItemProperty -Path hklm:software\dg -Name "Test" -value 0
}
```

Comment: try with `if([version] $val.'agent version' -eq [version] '7.8.5.005') {....`

Comment: When you write `7.8.5.005` without quotes in an _expression_, PowerShell creates a decimal number `7.8` and then looks for a property named `5.005` within that number object. Property doesn't exist, so it resolves to `$null`. So you are actually comparing a string to `$null`, which always resolves to `$false`. Unless the property `agent version` doesn't exist, then the expression would actually resolve to `$true`!

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to add '...' around the version number, so this ended up working for me: $val.'Agent version' -eq '7.8.5.005'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the great comments on the question:

**tl;dr**

Replace `$val.'agent version' -eq 7.8.5.005` with:

```bash
# Note the [version] cast, and the '...' around the RHS operand.
# Because the LHS uses [version], it isn't also needed before '7.8.5.5'
[version] $val.'agent version' -eq '7.8.5.5'  # Note: 0-padding is irrelevant
```

In general, to construct a literal `[version]` instance, you must cast from a *string*:

```bash
[version] '7.8.5.5' # '...' required
```

---

To address the *general* question implied by your post's *title*:

- **Enclosing a (literal) property name containing *special characters* such as *spaces* in `'...'` is indeed the right solution** (in the unlikely event that the name *itself* contains `'` instances, *double* them (`''`)).

  - As for *which* characters PowerShell considers special in a property name (identifier), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268127/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- **The Windows registry has *no* data type that directly represents a *version number*** - a *string* value (`REG_SZ`) is used to represent version numbers, and that translates into a .NET `[string]` instance via [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) or - to retrieve a registry *value* directly - via [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue).
- **Similarly, PowerShell also has *no* literal notation for version numbers**, but **you can cast a *string* to `[version]`** in order to construct a [`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version) instance.

  - As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) notes, the unquoted `7.8.5.005` literal effectively evaluates to `$null`, because it is parsed as `[double]` instance `7.8` on which you're trying to access the (implicitly stringified) `[double]` instance `5.005` *as a property*, which obviously doesn't exist.
  - You can gain insights into how PowerShell parses such expressions by enclosing them in a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), and drilling down into that script block's [`.Ast` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst) - note how `5.005` is listed as a `Member` access:

    ```bash
    PS> { 7.8.5.005 }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements.PipelineElements.Expression

    Expression      : 7.8
    Member          : 5.005
    Static          : False
    NullConditional : False
    StaticType      : System.Object
    Extent          : 7.8.5.005
    Parent          : 7.8.5.005
    ```

**Only `[version]` instances compare meaningfully *as version numbers***.

Since it is sufficient for the *LHS* of a comparison operation, such as with `-eq`, to be of type `[version]` in order to compare version numbers, you can take a shortcut and use a *string literal* as the RHS, as shown at the top.