# Replace values of all objects in XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have `XML` file with content below:

```
<Tenants>
    <Tenant name="tenant_1" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" site="98074" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\98074" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_2" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" site="62761" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\62761" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_3" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" site="24387" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\24387" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_4" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" site="85670" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\85670" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_5" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" site="29117" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\29117" />
</Tenants>
```

The `tenants` block contains an unknown count of an object in each of them `path` needs to be updated.
The `path` has a `UNC` format which is also unknown.
The task is to replace server name `1f7csgqde3l7.local` (which is unknown) but it's the same in each `path` of the `Tenants` block with a variable `$server`, and URL `8s0n3lewbf7v.local` with a variable `$url`.

What is the best approach to achieve this by using PowerShell?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65263942/11942268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best approach, but you can give it a try

Regex to get the UNC Path

```
[regex]$reg = "\\\\([a-z0-9_.$]+)\\"
```

Get-Content as XML

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path xml_file.xml
```

Loop through your structure, it simply replaces the matched UNC with your $url

```
Foreach($x in $xml.Tenants.Tenant){
   $x.path = $x.path.Replace($reg.Match($x.path).Value,"\\$url\")
}
```

And save it

```
$xml.Save("xml_file.xml")
```

Comment: Well yeah, this is the solution I was looking for, thanks

Comment: [xml]$config = Get-Content("$file")
Foreach($i in $config.'Tenant'.Tenants.childnodes){
 $i.path = $i.path.Replace($reg.Match($i.path).Value,"\\$server\")
 $i.url = "$url"
}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
$xml = [xml]'<Tenants>
    <Tenant name="tenant_1" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\98074_prod" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_2" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\62761_prod" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_3" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\24387_prod" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_4" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\85670_prod" />
    <Tenant name="tenant_5" url="8s0n3lewbf7v.local" path="\\1f7csgqde3l7.local\share\shared\29117_prod" />
</Tenants>
'
$new_server = "abcd123cde56"
$new_url="123456789asd.local"

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes(".//Tenants//Tenant");
foreach($node in $nodes) {
    $target_path =  $node.GetAttribute("path")
    $delim = ".lo"
    $name = $target_path -split $delim
    $newname = -join("\\",$new_server,$delim ,$name[1]);    
    $node.SetAttribute("path", $newname);
    $node.SetAttribute("url", $new_url);
}
```

That should result in

```
<Tenants>
  <Tenant name="tenant_1" url="123456789asd.local" path="\\abcd123cde56.local\share\shared\98074_prod" />
  <Tenant name="tenant_2" url="123456789asd.local" path="\\abcd123cde56.local\share\shared\62761_prod" />
  <Tenant name="tenant_3" url="123456789asd.local" path="\\abcd123cde56.local\share\shared\24387_prod" />
  <Tenant name="tenant_4" url="123456789asd.local" path="\\abcd123cde56.local\share\shared\85670_prod" />
  <Tenant name="tenant_5" url="123456789asd.local" path="\\abcd123cde56.local\share\shared\29117_prod" />
</Tenants>
```