# Loop through System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, loops

I am trying to loop through XML Linked Nodes Powershell, but I cannot seem to seperate them.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
    <Settings>
        <SomeSetting>
            <AAA>Some Value</AAA>
            <BBB>Some Value</BBB>
        </SomeSetting>
        <AnotherSetting>
            <CCC>Some Value</CCC>
            <DDD>Some Value</DDD>
        </AnotherSetting>
    </Settings>
</Test>
```

Now `$XML.Test.Settings` contains

> SomeSetting AnotherSetting
>
> ---
>
> SomeSetting AnotherSetting

I cannot loop through these elements individually. I want to loop through them where I get an array where the first item is **SomeSetting** and the second is **AnotherSetting**

I've tried leveraging GetEnumerator() and Looping through ($XML.Test.Settings).ChildNodes, but I keep ending up with a System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode object containing everything in one chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can use the hidden `Get_Name()` function on the ChildNode.

```
($Xml.DocumentElement.Settings).ChildNodes.Get_Name()
```

Not sure why `ChildNodes()` return grand child nodes otherwise.

Comment: Powershell has built in XML and Xpath optiopns to handle these scenarios. Kindly go through [Handling XMLs in PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509358/how-to-iterate-through-xml-in-powershell)